# Why only the first value of the select box is selected in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have done a process while Onclick of a select box, get an ajax response from the spring controller and load it in selectbox, Values are loaded but whenever I select the values in it, Only the first value is selected by default and not able to choose other values.

Whenever a Checkbox is clicked, For the first time the select box will be loaded from the model, from the next click of checkboxes need to load by the onclick which I have done below.

**NOTE:** There are n number of checkboxes in JSP Page

UPDATED CODE:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(
    function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxID=$(this).attr('id');
        var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form:form id="form" method="POST" action="mapping">'
                +'<label> Map the Selected field to Category ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   </label>'
                + '<br>'
                + '<br>'
                + '<br>'            
                + '<select id="category" name="category">'
                + '<c:forEach var="categoryList" items="${categoryList}">'
                + '<option value="${categoryList.category}"> <c:out value="${categoryList.category}" /></option>'
                + '</c:forEach>'
                + '</select>'
                + '<br>'
                + '<br>'
                + '<br>'
                + '<input type="button" name="mapBtn" id="mapBtn" value="MAP" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all"'
                + '</form:form></div>';
        $.fancybox.open(htmlStr,{
        'width'          : 950,
        'height'         : 1100, 
        'autoScale'      : false,
        'transitionIn'   : 'none',
        'transitionOut'  : 'none',
        'hideOnContentClick' : false 

    });
    }



    var data = $("#form").serializeArray();

    if(!isFirstSelect){
     $("#category").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "loadSelectBox",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){
                $("#category").empty();
                var options = '';
                for(var key in data){
                    options += "<option value='" + data[key] + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
                }
                $("#category").append(options);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },
        });

    }) 
    }
```

The data populated in selected box is not in ascending order eventhough values are loaded in Asc order in JSONObject from the controller.

Help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Can you show what `data`, and `#category` actually look like?

Comment: Values looks like  {"MONTH":"MONTH","TYPE OF DATA 5":"TYPE OF DATA 5","TYPE OF DATA 3":"TYPE OF DATA 3","TYPE OF DATA 4":"TYPE OF DATA 4"}

Comment: `whenever I select the values in it, Only the first value is selected by default`=>where is your value selection code?

Comment: Please check I have updated

Comment: What is the html element referring by this id `#category` ?

Comment: Thats inbuild pop up which I have given in var htmlStr

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution myself,

```
$.fancybox
.open(
    htmlStr,
    {
        'width'          : 950,
        'height'         : 1100, 
        'autoScale'      : false,
        'transitionIn'   : 'none',
        'transitionOut'  : 'none',
        'hideOnContentClick' : false, 
        'afterLoad': function(){
            if(!isFirstSelect){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "loadSelectBox",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#category").empty();
                    var options = '';
                    for(var key in data){
                        options += "<option value='" + data[key] + "'>" + data[key] + "</option>";
                    }
                    $("#category").append(options);
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                });
            }
            }
        });
```

I have done using 'afterLoad': while loading the fancy box

Thanks for the help.